# FuseFabric for FTP/File failover endpoints?

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, apache-zookeeper, fuseesb, fusefabric

I am creating a camel project which polls the local directory and pushes the files to a FTP location. I want to apply failover mechanism to my design. If want another fuse instance to be ready, if the current node fails.

Without any failover, two fuse instances can together poll the files. But I wanted the second node to poll the files, when the first node fails.

Is this scenario possible if I use FuseFabric ? I dont want anyother product choice, I have this product with me. But I want to know whether I can achieve this using Fabric ?

I am sure, this is possible in Web service endpoints. Not sure about file based endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a master component you can use, then only one is active at a time. And if the node fails, the another node is elected as the master.

Just put "master:someNameHere:" in front of any Camel endpoint in a route from, when you use Fuse Fabric. Where "someNameHere" is a logical name for the group.

For example

```
from("master:foo:ftp://bla-bla")
  .to("someWhere");
```

Comment: when we use master component/fabric components does client need to be aware of multiple addresses ? Can we give only one address exposed by fabric to clients and whether fabric can take care of delegating requests to different instances of fuse servers ?

Comment: There is a fabric component also, and all the client(s) needs to know is the logical name, eg "fabric:foo". Just that the client is using fabric also.